# Python dictionary return value with greatest value and redefine value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import ast # needed to read text as a dictionary
#import operator # needed to find maximum value
def define_words():
    '''
    Finds the word with the most occurences
    Asks for a definition
    Replaces entry in working dictionary
    Writes to a new final dictionary

    '''
    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/parole_di_dante.txt','r', encoding = "utf-8") as dic:
        dante_dict = ast.literal_eval(dic.read())# reads text as a dictionary
        #key_to_find = ''
        #definition = ''

        key_to_find = max(dante_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        print('The word needing to be defined is ', key_to_find)

        definition = input('Definition ? : ')
        for key_to_find in dante_dict.keys():
            #if key == key_to_find:
            dante_dict[key_to_find] = definition


    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/parole_di_dante.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(dante_dict))

    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/final_dante_dictionary.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as finalfile:
        finalfile.write(str(dante_dict))
```

I am using the above to return from a dictionary in the format:

```
{'sicuramente,': 11, 'beatitudo,': 11, 'concetti:': 15, 'ello:': 15, 'ello;': 16, 'favella,': 33, 'fene.': 13, 'ello,': 22, 'spira,': 66,'che': 560,…}
```

However when I run the above 'programme', say on the word 'che' that I define as 'that', what is returned is:

```
{'sicuramente,': 'that', 'beatitudo,': 'that', 'concetti:': 'that', 'ello:': 'that', 'ello;': 'that', 'favella,': 'that', 'fene.': 'that', 'ello,': 'that', 'spira,': 'that','che': 'that'…} instead of changing only the entry that I want to edit.
```

Obviously I am doing something stupid. I also not that I am not managing to remove punctuation. Grateful for your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not use this line of code:

```
key_to_find = max(dante_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

and here you set all words to the same definition.

```
    definition = input('Definition ? : ')
    for key_to_find in dante_dict.keys(): 
        #if key == key_to_find:
        dante_dict[key_to_find] = definition
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Not sure how to resolve this, but will work it through.